# Flaskにaxiosでjsonのlistを送る方法

Tags: python, vue.js, flask, axios

サーバサイドにFlask、フロントエンドにvue.jsを利用しています。

axiosを使って、データをサーバサイドに送りたいのですが、jsonをリスト型で送るのがうまくいっていません。ご教授頂けますでしょうか。

**バージョン**
Python 3.8
Vue 2.6.10

---

**vue.js**

```
axios.get('/testApi', {params:
    {
        jsonList: qs.stringify([
            {id:1, name: 'hoge1'},
            {id:2, name: 'hoge2'}
        ]
    )}})
```

**Python**

```
def get(self):
    # クライアントからの引数を受け取る
    parser = reqparse.RequestParser()

    # jsonListという名前の引数を受け取る
    parser.add_argument('jsonList')

    # dictionary形に変換
    args = dict(self.parser.parse_args())

    # 変換結果をコンソールに表示
    print(args['jsonList'])  # ①

    # parse.parse_qsで
    parsed1 = parse.parse_qs(args['jsonList'])

    print(parsed1)  # ②

    parsed2 = parse.parse_qsl(args['jsonList'])

    print(parsed2)  # ③
```

**①のprintの結果**

```
0%5Bid%5D=1&0%5Bname%5D=hoge1&1%5Bid%5D=1&1%5Bname%5D=hoge2
```

**②のprintの結果**

```
{'0[id]': ['1'], '0[name]': ['hoge1'], '1[id]': ['1'], '1[name]': ['hoge2']}
```

**③のprintの結果**

```
[('0[id]', '1'), ('0[name]', 'hoge1'), ('1[id]', '2'), ('1[name]', 'hoge2')]
```

通常のjson やlist の場合、parse.parse_qs・parse.parse_qslを利用するとうまく分解でき、
それぞれ、pythonのdictionaryやlistに置き換えられますが、
jsonのlistの場合、pythonでjsonのlistを整形できずに試行錯誤しております。

最終的には、pythonでも下記の形で処理したいのですが、どなたがお知恵をお貸しいただけますでしょうか。

```
[{id:1, name: 'hoge1'},{id:2, name: 'hoge2'}]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[axiosのパラメータ指定方法まとめ](https://qiita.com/taroc/items/f22f7dd5d6d5443c72a4) とか [axiosの使い方まとめ (GET/POST/例外処理)](https://www.sukerou.com/2019/05/axios.html) を見ると、`params:`を付けるのではなく、直接jsonを指定すれば良いのでは？

そして受ける方も [get_json()](https://flask.palletsprojects.com/en/1.1.x/api/#flask.Request.get_json) を使うとか。
[HTTPリクエストからJSONを受信する](https://riptutorial.com/ja/flask/example/5832/http%E3%83%AA%E3%82%AF%E3%82%A8%E3%82%B9%E3%83%88%E3%81%8B%E3%82%89json%E3%82%92%E5%8F%97%E4%BF%A1%E3%81%99%E3%82%8B)

この記事みたいに対策が必要かもしれませんが。
[Electron-Vue+axios+FlaskでHttp通信を行いたい](https://teratail.com/questions/196746)
[Setting header: 'Content-Type': 'application/json' is not working #86](https://github.com/axios/axios/issues/86)
[Setting 'Content-Type' header does not work. #2544](https://github.com/axios/axios/issues/2544)